# how to set UIButton's height anchor in swift?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I'm only using code to configure a view.
All views changed translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to false.
But it doesn't work the way I want it to.
The height anchor of the `disagreeButton` is strange.

```swift
contentView.addSubviews(datePickerView, dateSelectButton, triangleImageView, descriptionLabel, agreeButton, disagreeButton)

datePickerViewHeight = datePickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
dateSelectButtonHeight = dateSelectButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            datePickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            datePickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            datePickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            datePickerViewHeight ?? NSLayoutConstraint(),

            dateSelectButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datePickerView.bottomAnchor),
            dateSelectButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 76),
            dateSelectButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            dateSelectButtonHeight ?? NSLayoutConstraint(),

            triangleImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14),
            triangleImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10),
            triangleImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateSelectButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 9),
            triangleImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateSelectButton.centerYAnchor),

            descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateSelectButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            descriptionLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),

            agreeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            agreeButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
            agreeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -24),
            agreeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 58),

            disagreeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: agreeButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
            disagreeButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
            disagreeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -24),
            disagreeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 58),
            disagreeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)
])
```

[see storyboard debuging screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lMBM.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've over constrained the bottom button.  You set its top anchor and its bottom anchor.  That is enough to give the button a height.  So your height constraint is being ignored.  What do you want to happen in this case?

Comment: @vacawama I want button have height. because contentView is dynamic size view. so I must set button's height. so I give height anchor.

Comment: @vacawama is correct. Consider - you really *only* need to define two dimensions (sic?) for a button. Placement, and size. Placement is basically it's X/Y position (top, leading, trailing, bottom) BUT be aware that this *impllies* size if you define all four. Size if height/width, period. So with your `disagreeButton` that you wish a definitive height... do you wish it placed relative to the `agreeButton` or the `contentView`? Remove the top or bottom anchor and it should work. (You really should be getting some console messages with your code as is.)